# num cannot be resolved as a veriable

Tags: java

Im new to java and doesnt understand why its not working  and says "num cannot be resolved as a veriable" on the 2 "ifs" lines. thank you for your help

```
package basicJava1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DiscountCalculator{
  static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    double ₪ = 3.5748;
    System.out.println("Enter the price");
    double price = reader.nextInt();
    //
    System.out.println("Enter the discount");
    double dis = reader.nextInt();
    //
    if (dis > 99) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }   else {  
        System.out.println("the price is" + " " + (price-dis*(price/100)));
        double priceafter = (price-dis*(price/100));
        System.out.println("Would you like to exchange the discounted price from $ to ₪? (1=yes/2=no)");
        int num= reader.nextInt();
    } 
    if(num = 1) {
        System.out.println("The price is " + ((price-dis*(price/100))*₪) + "₪");
    }   else    {
        if(num = 2) {
        System.out.println("The price is " + (price-dis*(price/100)) + "$");
        } else {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that  to compare, you have to use `==` not `=` (which is for assigning a value) .

Comment: The variable is out of scope, there is much duplicates but I can't find one

Comment: It would be helpful if you could copypaste the exact compiler error message.

Answer (score 0):

`num` is not in scope where you use it, also `if(num = 1)` is not what you want, since the single `=` assigns 1 to `num` rather than compares them. For comparison, use `==`.

Change your code to something like this:

```
...

int num = 0; // some reasonable sentinel value
if (dis > 99) {
    System.out.println("error");
    // more error handling probably needed
} else {  
    System.out.println("the price is" + " " + (price-dis*(price/100)));
    double priceafter = (price-dis*(price/100));
        System.out.println("Would you like to exchange the discounted price from $ to ₪? (1=yes/2=no)");
    num = reader.nextInt();
} 

if(num == 1) {
    System.out.println("The price is " + ((price-dis*(price/100))*₪) + "₪");
} else {
...
```

Comment: Also double equation mark must be used to compare values in if statements.
if(num == 1) instead of if(num = 1)

Comment: @Arqan ooh, good catch, I'd glossed over that one

Comment: Maybe add the info that == should be used instead of =

Comment: @NielsNet I changed the code but I will point it out in words as well.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `num` isn't visible in the second section of your code, you need to declare that variable outside of the `if...else` statement:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
        int num = 0;
        double ₪ = 3.5748;
        System.out.println("Enter the price");
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a multiple things wrong in your current implementation:

1. The `=` in `if(num = 1)` and `if(num = 2)` should be `==` instead. `=` is for assigning value, and `==` is to check equality.
2. `int num = reader.nextInt();` is inside your else-block, so your next `if(num == 1)` won't know the `num` variable. This is currently the error you are getting.

So, try the following instead:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main{
  static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args){
    double ₪ = 3.5748;
    System.out.println("Enter the price");
    double price = reader.nextInt();
    //
    System.out.println("Enter the discount");
    double dis = reader.nextInt();
    //
    int num = 0;    // <- Now `num` is accessible by your second if-check below
    if(dis > 99){
      System.out.println("error");
    }else{
      double priceafter = price-dis*(price/100);
      System.out.println("the price is" + " " + priceafter);
      System.out.println("Would you like to exchange the discounted price from $ to ₪? (1=yes/2=no)");
      num = reader.nextInt();  // <- And we still set it here
    }

    if(num == 1){
      System.out.println("The price is " + ((price-dis*(price/100))*₪) + "₪");
    }else if(num == 2) {
      System.out.println("The price is " + (price-dis*(price/100)) + "$");
    }else{
      System.out.println("error");
    }
  }
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://ideone.com/cTSNll)

**Some additional things to note:**

1:

```
System.out.println("the price is" + " " + (price-dis*(price/100)));
double priceafter = (price-dis*(price/100));
```

Here you are doing the same calculation twice, so it's better to change it to:

```
double priceafter = price-dis*(price/100);
System.out.println("the price is" + " " + priceafter);
```

2:

```
if(num == 1){
  System.out.println("The price is " + ((price-dis*(price/100))*₪) + "₪");
}else{
  if(num == 2){
    System.out.println("The price is " + (price-dis*(price/100)) + "$");
  }else{
    System.out.println("error");
  }
}
```

I assume you are actually looking for an `if elseif else` case, so it should be this instead:

```
if(num == 1){
  System.out.println("The price is " + ((price-dis*(price/100))*₪) + "₪");
}else if(num == 2){
  System.out.println("The price is " + (price-dis*(price/100)) + "$");
}else{
  System.out.println("error");
}
```

3.

```
double price = reader.nextInt();
```

Shouldn't this be `.nextDouble()` instead? Why have a `double` price to begin with when you are only accepting integer inputs.. Same applies to the `discount` input.

---

*I did learn something new because of you today however. Never knew `₪` was a valid variable name.. I guess it's acting as some kind of special letter, since usually only letters, `_` or `$` are valid variable names as is (and digits can be used as well, but never as single variable digit or at the start of the variable.)*